# How to pass this <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" /> from html to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

In my project i accept the number of rows manually at the client end so I would like to know how to pass this `name[]` in the form to jsp page so I can receive all the values in the jsp page. Here the `modalDialog` which pops up new box where again we are allowed to enter the sub details of the existing main row. This means we have a main rows (Number of rows can be manually based on the client's needs) and the sub rows for each main row (even this is manually based on the client's needs). each input type name is identified individually.

```
<tr class="prototype">
<td><input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col4[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col3[]" value="" /></td>
<td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
<td><a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<h2>Modal Box</h2>
<table class="dynatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Debit </th>
<th>Credit</th>
<th><button class="add">Add</button></th>            
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="prototype">
<td><input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col4[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col3[]" value="" /></td>
<td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="sendMessage" class="buttonM bLightBlue" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use forms : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` notation isn't required when passing this type of data to a JSP (or rather, Java) backend.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
...
<input type="text" name="name" />
...
<input type="text" name="name" />
...
```

**Java/JSP**

```
String[] names = request.getParameterValues("name");
for (String name : names) {
    ...
}
```